# Copy Files coming in a folder over a network in C#

Tags: c#-2.0, file-io

I receive Files in a Folder at say 2 secs interval from a host machine over **" a TCP/IP network" at some Port X**. I need to have a service / watcher which will copy these Files to other location. I tried FileSystemWatcher, but it seems that the "Created event" of the watcher gets fired as soon as a byte is getting written to disk.

What is the best way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not run the copier on a timely basis? Say every 1 minute and copy files.

[FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) doesn't seem to be a good option where changes happen more frequently.